# checkbox should be always checked

Tags: javascript, html, angular, checkbox

I have a checkbox and I want to be checked always and it must be unchecked only if we wish to.

here is the html

```html
<input type="checkbox" 
    class="custom-control-input" 
    [(ngModel)]="productDetails.iscanRetrunable" 
    name="iscanRetrunable" checked>
```

Is it because I'm binding some value to it ?

Comment: Add the `disabled` attribute, keep in mind that a disabled input field is not send along when you submit the form.

Comment: I think it gets checked based on your ngmodel - I'm guessing that `productDetails.iscanRetrunable` needs to match the value of your checkbox (although you don't seem to have a value on the checkbox) in order for it to be checked.  If you want it to be only updateble by you, you can add a readonly or disabled attribute, but be careful - it will not post back if you do this and you will need to add a hidden input with the value - if it is checked

Answer (score -1):

It works, but you must initialize the starting `ngModel` binded value to true:

```
HTML:
    <input type="checkbox" 
        class="custom-control-input" 
        [(ngModel)]="checkboxvalue" 
        name="iscanRetrunable" checked>
      `,
    })

Component:
    export class App {
      checkboxvalue = true;
      constructor() {
      }
    }
```

[see this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pyi6VQNVWG4RnZrADN1r?p=preview)

Comment: can you please elaborate on how this is not working for you?

Comment: Thanks man!! I figured it out. Actually I was initializing the value of iscanReturanable to  empty and whenever the checkbox is checked im sending true via binding. Im sorry this was a stupid question. I should have checked what im binding to. Thanks anyways